# How to disable caching in devart dotConnect for Orcale - .netCore 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, devart, dotconnect

I have a licensed Devart dotConnect for Oracle.

I'm struggling to get new data from my Entities because they are always returning cached data!
And i can't find any way anywhere how to disable caching completely.

Question is: How to completely disable caching?

*Env: .netCore 3.1*

*Version: Devart.Data.Oracle.EFCore 9.10*

Answer (score 0):

We recommend you to dispose current context object and create the new one to get updated data.

Also, refer to:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder.usequerytrackingbehavior?view=efcore-3.1

Comment: This is way not helpful!
i need a general configuration for cache management! I keep getting outdated data!

Comment: Please dispose your context and create the new one to get up-to-date data.